# Make a parallelogram with one side in CSS3

Tags: html, css

I have make a parallelogram with CSS3. With this code:

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
}
```

Now I have the right and left bevel. But i want only to the righ the bevel. How can i make that?

Thanks

Comment: So you want a trapezium?

Comment: I want this figure: http://mikevierwind.nl/figure.jpg

Comment: That would be a trapezium, yes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example and the result code: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC4EK/).

```
<style type="text/css">
#trapezoid {
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
</style>
<div id="trapezoid"></div>
```

*This will create a trapezoid.*

**Or this:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
    background: red;
}
</style>
<div id="parallelogram"></div>
```

*This will create a parallelogram*

Here is an article about creating all kinds of shapes with CSS only and a single HTML element. It's a very interesting way for creating every shape from a triangle to a star.
[The Shapes of CSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: WTH? both #trapezoid and #parallelogram have the same CSS. This is not a correct answer.