# How do I draw a Diagonal div?

Tags: html, css

How do I draw a diagonal `div` in CSS? Google only reveals how to draw diagonal "lines", but I could not understand how to make that for `div`'s.

In the pic below, the blue part is the `div`:

[image]

Comment: You could use css transform rotate and put in inside another box to have straight horizontal lines.

Comment: what should happen is text increases?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462535/make-a-parallelogram-with-one-side-in-css3

Comment: @Fabrizio, that's a good question. I guess I would prefer the division to expand, as normal, without changing the diagonal shape, if you know what I mean, but in trying to do this without javascript so that might be a bit difficult.

Comment: Thank you @Stephan, that code is spot on.

Comment: To give an element a custom non-rectangular shape, you use the shape-inside and shape-outside properties. I found the following tutorial on the creation of non rectangular layouts with css very helpful: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Comment: Thank you @The_Fritz I am looking at this now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use [CSS3 transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) [`skewY()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#funcdef-skewy) function with positive value for the *parent* and negative value for the *child* wrapper element to achieve the effect.

```css
.parent {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
}

.parent > .child {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform: skewY(5deg);
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bugab/1/edit)**.

From the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#SkewYDefined):

> `skewY()` specifies a 2D skew transformation along the Y axis by the
>   given angle.

It's worth noting that the using [`skewY()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#funcdef-skewy) won't change the width of the transformed elements.

Also **mind** the *child* selector. It's better to use direct [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) `.parent > .child` rather than [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) to negate the transform on the *child* element.

Comment: Thank you so much. I use the skew tool everyday in image editors, why the hell did I not think to search for skew?! Much appreciated!

Comment: I am waiting for the timer to run out so I can accept the answer. I will be back.

Comment: Just remember that `transform` does not work in opera browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Really cool codes using background-image:
https://codepen.io/PositionRelativ/pen/Ichrg

```
 .one{
   background-color: #013A6B;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, #013A6B 50%, #004E95 50%);
   min-height: 500px;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used clip-path to get the same result. here is my code

```css
body
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.polygon
{
 height: 100vh;
 background: #00A2E8;
 clip-path: polygon(0 50%, 100% 0,100% 50%,0 100%);
 position: relative;
}
.content
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Clippath</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clip.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="polygon">
   <div class="content">
   <h2 class="head">heading</h2>
   <p>lorem ipsum dolar sit amet lol</p>
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Beware: `clip-path` has [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)

Answer (score 4):

Use :

```
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

Just add prefixes for all browsers (-webKit, -moz, ... )