# How to design Diagonal Type DIV with V shape Style?

Tags: html, css, border, shapes, diagonal

How to Design DIV with full width in Diagonal Style but with V Shape in Top & Bottom Border.

Note : I had already tried many Possible Solutions to design exactly same like Image Reference I provided but yet I dont find any Optimized Solutions for this.
Skew Method, Top & Bottom Div with assigning Border Width with one Middle (total 3 Div Set Styles I had tried but it allowed me only with shaping 2 corners of div but yet i wont find any possible solution.

[DIV CSS Shaping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOrhS.png)

This is the thing which I want to Design.

Thanks in Advance for Help.

his is variation of code which I had tried :

```css
.tridiv{
 width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000000;
    height: 500px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
/*-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 71%, 50% 100%, 0 65%, 0 0, 51% 33%);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 71%, 50% 100%, 0 65%, 0 0, 51% 33%);*/
 }

.tridiv:before {
    content:"";
    -moz-transform: skewX(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(10deg);
    transform: skewX(10deg);
    width: 90%;
    left: 0;
 right:0;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #555;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
 margin:0 auto
}


.box {
  background-color: skyblue;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5% 20px; /* Added a percentage value for top/bottom padding to keep the wrapper inside of the parent */
  
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
}

.box > .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -moz-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(5deg);
  -o-transform: skewY(5deg);
  transform: skewY(5deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
        <p>This is a sub-heading</p>
        <p>
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352311/how-do-i-draw-a-diagonal-div/22352383#22352383">
            How do I draw a Diagonal div?
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="tridiv">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam eu dapibus quam. Proin non faucibus nisi. Quisque ac mi lectus. Suspendisse metus purus, congue nec ornare eu, hendrerit vel sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas volutpat diam elementum lacus porta rhoncus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean volutpat massa quis nulla elementum et commodo ligula fringilla. Sed pellentesque, risus eu rutrum volutpat, sem elit feugiat tellus, id molestie sapien turpis sit amet ante. Maecenas nec mollis orci. Integer lacus nulla, facilisis ac ullamcorper sit amet, commodo quis est. Quisque pharetra urna vitae leo suscipit vulputate luctus enim tincidunt. Curabitur blandit lobortis lobortis. Phasellus rhoncus arcu sed nunc tempus ut dictum tellus elementum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try clip-path using [Clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: Maybe you could show us your best approach? Also, don't forget that sometimes a background image really is the simplest solution. My first thought, however, would be `:before` and `:after` to insert rectangles, then rotate them. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: @Ori Drori : I had check it it is seriously nice thing but I think this tool might not word with 100% of display.

Comment: @domdom: at a first sight i had tried to designed it with bg image but i need to use various view-ports for such segments so i can not use it.

Comment: @domdom : I had also tried it with :before and :after for div but only allow me to code only for either top or bottom both the side wont be coded in single pan.

Comment: @BhargavJoshi - see answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I added an answer with an example using `::before` and `::after`, but it isn't the best piece of CSS out there...

Comment: Of course, `canvas` or `svg` would also be possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot testing I found one Possible Solution for this Issue and I think it might work perfectly.

Please check the Code and if you guys find any issue or bug so will try sort out this.

```css
.wrapper{width:100%; margin:0 auto; background:#efefef; display:block; min-height:500px; box-sizing: border-box; position: relative; overflow: hidden;}

/* First Div which work as Parent DIV */
.firstdiv{
 width:0;
 height:270px;
 border-top: 80px solid #fff;
 border-left: 50vw solid #0eaaee;
 border-right: 50vw solid #0eaaee;
 border-bottom:0;
}

/* Second DIV which work as Overlapping DIV*/
.seconddiv{
 width:0;
 height:130px;
 border-top: 80px solid #0eaaee;
 border-left: 50vw solid #fff;
 border-right: 50vw solid #fff;
 border-bottom:0;
 background:#fff
 
}
/* Content Section for Main Parent DIV Targetting with Content */
.content{position:relative; width:90%; margin:-235px auto auto auto; height:200px; color:#fff; font-family:Roboto Condensed; text-align:center}
.content h1{font-size:46px;}
.content p{ font-size:18px; line-height:28px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="firstdiv">
    </div>
        <div class="content">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras quis turpis a lorem pellentesque placerat et nec libero. Proin vitae nulla eget est bibendum commodo vitae id orci. Nam et lacinia ex. Nullam eget condimentum diam, in ultricies nibh. Vestibulum scelerisque tempus eros quis bibendum. Maecenas at pulvinar libero. Fusce commodo leo non tempor facilisis.</p>
        </div>
    
    <div class="seconddiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too good with CSS, but as a proof of concept, here is a messy example showing that you could do it with `::before`, `::after` and `transform`.

This has the upside that `transform` has better browser support than `clip-path`. Some tweaking (including proper math) is most likely necessary though...

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.arrow-down::before,
.arrow-down::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: -10;
  background: #5b9aff;
}

.arrow-down::before {
  left: -60px;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
}

.arrow-down::after {
  left: 248px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.arrow-down {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.arrow-down h1 {
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrow-down">
    <h1>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet
</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet<br>
      Yadda dadda, bleh foo bar<br>
      Aww yeah, CSS is cool
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so far for a fixed width it it good solution but for full width it a lot problems.!

Comment: Yeah, not quite sure if it can work with a dynamic width. I'd guess you'd need to employ relative units (`%`) or `calc()` then.