# Create diagonal background box

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to do something like the following:
[image]

The code I currently have loads the image as the background but I cannot seem to get the diagonal div box on top of the image and also make it diagonal

**HTML**

```
<div>

    <style>
        landingDiv {
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        img.bg {
            /* Set rules to fill background */
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 1024px;
            /* Set up proportionate scaling */
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            /* Set up positioning */
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            opacity: 10;
            background-image: url("https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/155/moviebackground/the-dark-knight-51f269c2ce53a.jpg")
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
            img.bg {
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -512px; /* 50% */
            }
        }
    </style>
    <img class="landingDiv bg" />

    <div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
        Hey
    </div>

</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mv75qn9c/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I draw a Diagonal div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22352311/how-do-i-draw-a-diagonal-div)

Comment: set the position:relative to div and give a try

Comment: Plus 1 for batman , I think you can use linear-gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a gradient overlay in the background-image rule :

```
 background-image:
     linear-gradient(-10deg, transparent 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 80%, transparent 80%), 
     url("https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/155/moviebackground/the-dark-knight-51f269c2ce53a.jpg")
```

```css
landingDiv {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 10;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-10deg, transparent 20%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 20%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.3) 80%, transparent 80%), url("https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/155/moviebackground/the-dark-knight-51f269c2ce53a.jpg")
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;
    /* 50% */
  }
}
```

```html
<div>

  <img class="landingDiv bg" />

  <div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
    Hey
  </div>

</div>
```

A few possible examples:

- https://jsfiddle.net/mv75qn9c/1/ (darker)
- https://jsfiddle.net/mv75qn9c/2/ (lighter)
- any rgba() colors will do , same or mixed https://jsfiddle.net/mv75qn9c/3/

tune degrees and transparent/rgba() areas to your needs.

**Note :** crispy edges can be blurred setting values of color stop and start with litlle difference in values :

```
linear-gradient(-10deg, transparent 20%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 20.1%, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 80%, transparent 80.1%)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Z-index** property might help here as i see your problem,

The **z-index** property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. ***Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).***

So here if you want your image in background and div in the front so

**Add**

```
       img.bg { z-index:-1 ;}
```

So here you can see that am giving -1 to img.bg which makes it low priority compair to div ... you can now use it whatever you want.

```css
            landingDiv {
                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                -moz-background-size: cover;
                -o-background-size: cover;
                background-size: cover;
            }
    
            img.bg {
                /* Set rules to fill background */
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 1024px;
                /* Set up proportionate scaling */
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                /* Set up positioning */
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                opacity: 10;
                background-image: url("https://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/movies/155/moviebackground/the-dark-knight-51f269c2ce53a.jpg");
                
                
              z-index : -1 ;
            
            }
            
    
            @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
                img.bg {
                    left: 50%;
                    margin-left: -512px; /* 50% */
                }
            }
```

```html
    <div>
    
        
        <img class="landingDiv bg" />
    
        <div style="height: 30px; width: 100%; background-color: gray;">
            Hey
        </div>
    
    </div>
```